# How to Check if a SQL Server Login has Role 'SysAdmin'

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am working on a PowerShell script that checks a specified SQL Server to see if a particular login (let's call it 'ContractUser') has successfully been given the role of a SysAdmin. I am looking for a way to script a simple if/then check to see if that login has the SysAdmin role.

I have found many examples online that show how to retrieve the entire list of SysAdmin logins, but have not yet figured out how to alter those scripts to only check the server for a single login. For example, the following script gets all logins with SysAdmin role and then does something special for them.

```
$SQLSvr = "SQLServername\Instancename";
$MySQL = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server $SQLSvr;
$SQLLogins = $MySQL.Logins;

$SysAdmins = $null;
$SysAdmins = foreach ($SQLUser in $SQLLogins) {
    foreach ($role in $SQLUser.ListMembers()) {
        if ($role -match 'sysadmin') {
            ...do stuff...
        };
    };
};
```

I tried to alter that a bit and came up with the following code, which does not return results as expected (I know that the server I am checking has that login and that login in a sysadmin, yet the script says otherwise):

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo") | Out-Null

$serverConnection = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection
$serverConnection.ServerInstance=$SQLServer
$server = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Server($serverConnection)
$SQLLogins = $server.Logins
$loginIsSysadmin = "No"
foreach ($SQLLogin in $SQLLogins) {
    $SQLRoles = $SQLLogin.ListMembers()
    if ($SQLRoles -eq "SysAdmin" -and $SQLLogin.name -eq "ContractUser") {
        $loginIsSysadmin = "Yes"
        break
    }
}
```

I expect that my script would change the variable `$loginIsSysadmin` to "Yes" which I could then do a simple check against for output and further actions. However, that variable remains a "No" after running the script.

Any input as to what I am doing wrong will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The IS_SRVROLEMEMBER (Transact-SQL) perhaps provides a more all-encompassing method over direct sql querying of logins.  For example it checks:

1. Whether the login exists, if so, if it is a direct or indirect member of sysadmin.
2. If it does not exist, if it is a member of sysadmin through indirect membership of a Windows group (or group of groups) that itself is mapped to a login.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/is-srvrolemember-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

See Example usage below:

```
function QueryDatabaseScript($databaseServer, $dbScript, $timeout)
{
    # Query and return recordset array for passed T-SQL string
    $SQLConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $SQLConnection.ConnectionString = "server=$($databaseServer);Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;"

    try
    {        
        $SQLConnection.Open()
        $SQLCommand = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
        $SQLCommand.Connection = $SQLConnection 
        $SQLCommand.CommandTimeout = $timeout
        
        $SQLCommand.CommandText = $dbScript
        $reader = $SQLCommand.ExecuteReader()

        $recordsetArray = @()
        while ($reader.Read())
        {
            $recordsetArray += $reader[0]
        }

        $SQLConnection.Close()
        $SQLConnection.Dispose()
    }
    catch
    {
        write-host "QueryDatabaseScript failed.`nError: $($_.Exception.Message)"
        $SQLConnection.Dispose()
        throw $_
    }

    return $recordsetArray
}

$sqlSvr = 'SQLServername\Instancename';

$queryResults = QueryDatabaseScript $sqlSvr "select Is_SrvRoleMember('sysadmin')" 0
$isSysadmin = $queryResults[0]
write-host "Current user is a sysadmin: $isSysadmin"

$sqlLogin = 'ContractUser'
$queryResults = QueryDatabaseScript $sqlSvr "select Is_SrvRoleMember('sysadmin', '$sqlLogin')" 0
$isSysadmin = $queryResults[0]
write-host "$sqlLogin is a sysadmin: $isSysadmin"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, as usual, [invoke-sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd) is your friend.  SMO is not.

Eg

```
$login = 'sa'
$sql = @"
    select r.name role_name, m.name member_name
    from sys.server_principals r
    join sys.server_role_members rm
      on r.principal_id = rm.role_principal_id
    join sys.server_principals m
      on m.principal_id = rm.member_principal_id
    where m.name = '$login'
"@
$isSysadmin = ( @(invoke-sqlcmd $sql ).Count -eq 1 )
write-host "Is a sysadmin: $isSysadmin"
```